# Add label to SKSpriteNode without it being touchable

Tags: sprite-kit, touch, sklabelnode

How do I turn off interaction for a childnode?

I'm adding labels to a bunch of sprites, beneath the sprite, describing what they are. The sprites themselves are touchable, and have code that responds when touchesBegun etc.

The labels do not visually overlap the sprite, they're fully beneath the visual representation of the Sprites, but they are children of their respective Sprite, and I'd like to keep it that way.

But I don't want the labels to respond to touch.

I set the labels to

```
myLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

But this doesn't make any difference, they're still responding to touch as if they're the Sprite.

Comment: Try `label.isPaused = true`. No idea if it will work, but I feel like it could do something...

Answer (score 1):

By default `isUserInteractionEnabled` is [false](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483109-isuserinteractionenabled) then the touch on a child like a `SKLabelNode` is, by default, a simple touch handled to the main (or parent) class (the object is here, exist but if you don't implement any action, you simply touch it)

If you set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to **true** on a subclassed `SKNode` then the touch delegates will called inside this specific class.
So, you can handle the touch for the label (as your case) within its class.

Comment: Does this mean the handling of the touch on the label must be handled, and  manually rejected, because otherwise (when it's interaction is turned off) it's passing the touch on, anyways?

Comment: If you don't want the touch on the label, you must handled in the main parent class e manually "rejected" if you mean "do nothing with it"

Comment: Ok. Fine. But how? I'm not following, at all.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40419334/1894067 that explain in code a similar issue